# How set failover and cluster way in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: devops, admin, activemq-artemis

Where to add the configuration file and where to locate the config file.

Comment: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-server.html

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ Artemis default installation includes the ARTEMIS_HOME directory where the distribution has been extracted and a broker instance directory containing all the configuration and runtime data, see the [installation documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-server.html) for further details.

The cluster settings are defined in the the server configuration file `broker.xml` included in the `etc` directory of the broker instance, see the [cluster documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html) for further details.

The ActiveMQ Artemis Core client supports [automatic failover](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#automatic-client-failover) for servers with High Availability, see the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html) for further details.